# List of all the templates in flask

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

Is there a programmatic (built-in) way of getting all the templates along with their routes in a flask app? Something like:

```
{'route_a': 'template_name.html',
 'route_b': 'template_name.html',
 ...
}
```

I mean I can create a mapping like this by parsing the templates, directory, but just wondering if there is any built-in functionality to construct this. I have already tried looking into the `app.url_map` items, but don't see any template related mappings..

Answer (score 3):

No, this is not possible. Templates don't have routes. Routes render templates. There is no way to know what templates are rendered without actually evaluating each route. There is no guarantee that only one route renders a template, or that a route only renders one template.